# Whenever I use the change additional information option, it does not change - Magento 1.9.1

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, configuration, additional-information

In **Magento 1.9.1** whenever I use the change product option from the dropdown the product price and availability it will change but the `additional information` is not changed.

I want it to be so that if the user changes the drop-down then the `additional information` of that particular product also changes. [image]

Can anyone tell me why it will not change and how to fix this issue? Any extension is available for that?